# How to get list of active subscribers in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am trying to get a list of all users with active subscriptions, but for the life of me can't seem to get something working.

If I look at the users in the dashboard, I see all the active members have a "Abonné" role.

So I've set up my shortcode like this:

```
function custom_get_members( ){
$args1 = array(
        'role' => 'Abonné',
        'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
$subscribers = get_users($args1);

$output = '<ul>';
    foreach ($subscribers as $user) {
        $output .= '<li>' . $user->display_name.'['.$user->user_email . ']</li>';
        }
$output .= '</ul>';

return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'annuaire', 'custom_get_members' );
```

But I always get 0 results, even though we have currently over 50 subscribers.

Running the WooCommerce with Subscription and Membership.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

**Updated** *(with an additional customized function for your shortcode)*

1) The following custom function that makes a very light SQL query will return an array of users Ids from all active subscribers:

```
function get_active_subscribers_ids(){
    global $wpdb;

    // Return an array of user Ids active subscribers
    return $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT DISTINCT pm.meta_value
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm
            ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_subscription'
        AND p.post_status = 'wc-active'
        AND pm.meta_key = '_customer_user'
    " );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

2) For your shortcode, I have changed this function to get directly the `display_name` and `user_email`:

```
function get_all_active_subscribers(){
    global $wpdb;

    return $wpdb->get_results( "
        SELECT DISTINCT u.*
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm
            ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}users as u
            ON pm.meta_value = u.ID
        WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_subscription'
        AND p.post_status = 'wc-active'
        AND pm.meta_key = '_customer_user'
    " );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**Usage in your shortcode:**

```
function custom_get_members( ){
    $output = '<ul>';

    // Loop through active subscribers
    foreach ( get_all_active_subscribers() as $user ) {
        $output .= '<li>' . $user->display_name.'['.$user->user_email . ']</li>';
    }
    return $output . '</ul>';
}
add_shortcode( 'annuaire', 'custom_get_members' );
```

Tested and works with a much lighter query and code.

Comment: What an awesome idea!

Comment: @Mr.Jo Thank you Mister Jo